# no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I'm trying to implement a simple ostream_itreator, which streams every N-th element, but i get a type error

```
error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<outIterator<int> >’
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_OI>::value_type _ValueTypeO;
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


template<class T>
class outIterator {
    std::ostream *stream;
    size_t N;
    const char* delim;
    size_t counter = 0;
public:
    // initialization
    outIterator(std::ostream& out)
    : stream(&out)
    , N(1)
    , delim(" ")
    {}

    outIterator(std::ostream& out, size_t N, const char* delimiter)
    : stream(&out)
    , N(N)
    , delim(delimiter)
    {}

    // =
    outIterator<T>& operator= (const T& value) {
        if (counter % N == 0){
            *stream << value << delim;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    outIterator<int> out(std::cout, 2, " ");
    std::vector<int> vec {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), out);
    return 0;
}
```

Also i didn't include overloadings ++ and ++(int). They increment counter and return *this.
And * overloading that returns *this

Error description:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:378:57: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<outIterator<int> >’
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_OI>::value_type _ValueTypeO;
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:383:9: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<outIterator<int> >’
       const bool __simple = (__is_trivial(_ValueTypeI)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       && __is_pointer<_II>::__value
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       && __is_pointer<_OI>::__value
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         && __are_same<_ValueTypeI, _ValueTypeO>::__value);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/output. Copy & paste the text here instead.

Comment: 1. I have an error: a lot of code, add some details.
2. Why?

Comment: Image links can be broken, and SO questions are meant to be references that other people can see in the future. Plus, sometimes the people wanting to help with the question want to look up something from the error, or google it. If the error is in text form, it makes this much easier. BTW, thank you for editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Custom iterator types must either contain member typedefs for `difference_type`, `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, and `iterator_category` or specialize `std::iterator_traits` to provide the same.

In your specific case, you should modify your `outIterator` template like this:

```
template <typename T>
class outIterator {
//...
public:
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
//...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write your iterator, you have to include some variable. You only need to include these:

```
template <class T>
class iterator {
    public:
        // code ...   
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using reference = value_type&;
        // code ...
 }
```